# reorder existing divs using jquery sortable in a html file

Tags: jquery, html

i have the html file like

```
<div id="sortable"><div id="div1">Item 1</div> <div id="div2">Item 2 </div></div>
```

i applyed jquery sortable on div id "sortable" and i succeed sorting divs and got the order.
Now i have to save the order in the html file also.
help me to save the order and redesign based on the order.

Comment: You can use any server side program and store it in session or you can save it in file

Answer (score 1):

You can 'grab' the HTML straight out of the `#sortable` div by calling `$('#sortable').html()`